# Convolution with standard mollifier equals to itself

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We know that if a function $u\in C（\Omega）$ satisfies mean value property（i.e. harmonic），it holds that
$$ u*\phi_{\varepsilon}=u $$
where $\phi_{\varepsilon}$ is standard mollifier. My question is that when the formula holds, can we deduce that $u$ must be a harmonic function or other properties"

Comment: What exactly is $\phi_\epsilon$? This is important for your question, and "standard mollifier" does not have a universally accepted definition.